# Github Enterprise Mac Client won't show my Private repositories

Tags: git, macos, github, github-for-mac, github-enterprise

Any mac users, using enterprise github mac client? I am logged in with my Enterprise account only, i do not have a regular github account associated with this account.

I am having issues looking at my repositories, from github enterprise, do i need to login with a regular account in order to see my enterprise repos?.

Yes my account is already setup in the terminal, and there is no problems when i got through terminal, but for this project i will mainly like to use the github mac client. Thank you guys!

Comment: What version of GitHub Enterprise are you running? We had to open a ticket with them regarding the Mac client and GHE 11.10.3xx

Comment: @busse I believe they were able to fix this situation with the last update, I updated to "Bae's Branch (210)" build and its working now, afterwards i was also able to update my client to "Topologically Delicious (211)" and everything seems good now. I clicked on the little cloud on the top right from client.